# Podio get item by reference

Tags: podio

I try to get references of a specific item using Podio's get_references method in PHP (https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-references-22439). Usually, when there's nothing to return, NULL is returned, but this time undefined is returned. My item exists and has references. I can access my item without problem.

I've also simulated the API request by Podio's doc and the returned result is also undefined.

Has someone already had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API Operation doesn't do what you think it does. It's for getting automatic references which I think are no longer displayed anywhere.

If all your references are in the same app use Filter Items to get all items in an app that references another item: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747

If your references are in multiple apps use Get references to item using field: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-references-to-item-by-field-7403920